# How to use a where condition in SQL Server for summing data from a year to another year that is from financial year to next year?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table, I have two columns - one is month with values 1,2,...12, and the other is year 2014,...2019.

I want to sum a column for a period that is from April 2014 to April 2015 - how can I specify a condition to get these values?

Please help me to solve this. I found this [article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145854/mysql-fetch-records-between-two-specific-months-and-years/145856) on the web but I don't have a date field as mentioned in this link. Please help, and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From April 2014 to April 2015, upper-exclusive:

```
SELECT SUM(MyNum)
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE ((MyYear = 2014 AND MyMonth >= 4)
     OR (MyYear = 2015 AND MyMonth < 4))
```

If it crosses multiple years, e.g. from April 2014 to April 2019:

```
SELECT SUM(MyNum)
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE ((MyYear = 2014 AND MyMonth >= 4)
     OR (MyYear BETWEEN 2015 AND 2018)
     OR (MyYear = 2019 AND MyMonth < 4))
```

Comment: how can I give range April 2016 - Jan 2017, April 2017 - Jan 2018, April 2018 - Jan 2019, April 2019 - Jan 2020 @Andreas

Comment: @Gopipuli Using combination of `AND`, `OR`, `=`, and `<=`. Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: Is there any alternate way to shorten this query @Andreas
SELECT
   '2016 - 17' as 'Years',
   SUM("svalue") as 'Value',
   'Sale' as 'Type',
   "code" as 'FACode',
   'Apr 1 - Jan 31' as 'Period'
FROM  "FCJOIN" 
WHERE  "code"  IN
 (
  SELECT "fccode"
 FROM  "fcdetails" 
 )
 AND (("year"  = '2016'
 AND "month"  >= '04')
 OR ("year"  = '2017'
 AND "month"  <= '01'))
GROUP BY  "code" 
UNION ALL
 Next Year Upto 4Years .

Answer (score 1):

Easier to work with dates, If there isnt a daet field, we could compare as follows

```
select sum(mysum)
  from mytable
where cast(concat(cast(myYear as varchar(4)),'-',cast(myMonth as varchar(4)),'-01') as date) >='2014-04-01'
  and cast(concat(cast(myYear as varchar(4)),'-',cast(myMonth as varchar(4)),'-01') as date)  <'2019-04-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do:

```
select sum(column)
from t cross apply
     (values (datefromparts(year, month, 1))
     ) v(yyyymm)
where v.yyyymm >= '2014-04-01' and
      v.yyyymm <= '2015-04-01';
```

Dates are so much easier to work with when using dates.

In fact, they are so simple, I would recommend adding a computed column into the table:

```
alter table t add column yyyymm as (datefromparts(year, month, 1));
```

Then the query would simply be:

```
select sum(column)
from t 
where t.yyyymm >= '2014-04-01' and
      t.yyyymm <= '2015-04-01';
```

Simple.  Readable.  And you can persist `yyyymm` and use an index.